# Solving ODE with derivative boundary condition with finite difference method by central approximation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, approximation, finite-differences, approximate-integration

I am trying to solve the following ODE:

$$ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=y(x) $$
Where I have two boundary conditions: $ y(0)=10 $; and $ \frac{dy(x\rightarrow\inf)}{dx}=0 $

I am trying to solve the problem through finite difference by central approximation, so:

$$ y''(x_i)=\frac{f(x_{i+1})-2\cdot y(x_i)+y(x_{i-1})}{h^2} $$

Which if plugged into my initial ODE:

$$ y(x_{i+1})+(-2-h^2)\cdot y(x_i)+y(x_{i-1})=0 $$

In this case I am discretizing over a range of: $ 0\leq x \leq 5$, with 500 nodes (so $h=0.01$), and $I$ goes from 1 to $N+1$, where the approximated ODE would be valid for $2\leq i \leq N$ (all discretized points except for the boundaries.

Hope I made sense so far and you are still with me here, my question is, how do I set up the right hand side boundary condition $ (\frac{dy(x\rightarrow\inf)}{dx}=0) $, since I do not have a specific value to set it to?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: The basis solutions are $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$, you want only the second, so demand that $y'(b)+y(b)=0$ at some largish $b$. Essentially, you construct some solution approximation that converges to the saddle point for the segment $[b,\infty)$ and the continuation properties give the boundary conditions at $b$.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @LutzLehmann unfortunately I'm not sure I follow through. Why would I set $y'(b)+y(b)=0$, and how would I construct a solution approximation?

Comment: For $x>b$ you want $y_{far}(x)=y(b)e^{b-x}$, at the moment ignoring that you want the same for $x<b$. Its derivative is $y_{far}(x)=-y(b)e^{b-x}$. At $x=b$ this gives $y'_{far}(b)=-y(b)$. By continuity of the derivative also $y'(b)=-y(b)$ for the boundary values of the function on $[0,b]$.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of coming across as overbearing, I will answer my own question (XD)... I came across this [MIT post](https://web.mit.edu/10.001/Web/Course_Notes/Differential_Equations_Notes/node9.html) that solves exactly this problem. The condition can be evaluated again by using finite difference, where by central approximation:
$$ \frac{dy(x_i)}{dx}=\frac{y(x_{i+1})-y(x_{i-1})}{2\cdot h} $$
Applied to the BC:
$$ \frac{dy(x_N)}{dx}=\frac{y(x_{N+1})-y(x_{N-1})}{2\cdot h}=0\rightarrow y(x_{N+1})-y(x_{N-1}) \approx y(x_{N+2})-y(x_{N})=0$$
Where the approximation works under the assumption of $ h\rightarrow 0$. Here we are adding an additional term $(y_{N+2})$, so the system of equations used to solve the approximated ODEs at each of the discretized points will also have to grow from N+1, to N+2, where the new value added to the end will be "fictitious", and should later be removed from the final solution.

I'm unsure as to how well I explained this, but in case of any doubt, follow the link if it's still up, they do a far better job at explaining it than me :').

Comment: This is usually called "ghost cells", introducing points that lie outside the integration interval.